# Flutter: Unwanted space beneath TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I have an issue where the Flutter TextField doesn't fill its set height. The blue Container shows the size that the TextField should be.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(



        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 56,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              // Sizes
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 56),

              // Fill color
              fillColor: Colors.grey,
              filled: true,

              // Hint text
              hintText: "Password",

              // Borders
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                borderSide:
                    const BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                borderSide:
                    const BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Copying this code into [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev) reveals the issue.

#### Edit

After removing the height of the container (`// height: 56,`) there is still a blue gap underneath the TextField. This means that the TextField is taking up the correct height but the InputDecoration is not.

Comment: Can you include snippet without depending on external data.

Comment: Thanks. The code no longer depends on external data.

Comment: Do you like to have counter ?

Comment: Removing the counter and maxLength doesn't make a difference.

Comment: also what will be scroll direction  for Text?

Comment: Default height is `48`

Comment: How can I change that default height?

Comment: Inspecting widgets we can see both are 56px height. The gap you see in the textfield belongs to it. I don't know if you can get ride of it. There was an issue opened about it on the flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15483

Answer (score 0):

If you want the TextField widget to expand verticaly you need to set its expands property to true.
Also the property maxLines need to be set to null to avoid failing the assertion.
As the documentation says on the expands property:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/expands.html

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height:100,
          child: TextField(
            expands: true,
            maxLines: null,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              // Sizes
              // Fill color
              fillColor: Colors.grey,
              filled: true,

              // Hint text
              hintText: "Password",

              // Icons
              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.key_rounded),
              prefixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: 24 + 16 * 2,
              ),
              suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.visibility),
              suffixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: 24 + 16 * 2,
              ),

              // Borders
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                borderSide:
                    const BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                borderSide:
                    const BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does technically work. In practice this enables the user to enter multiple lines which is not useful in my case as it's a password form field.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `contentPadding` under the `InputDecoration`.

**Voila!**

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out that by removing `constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 56),` and precisely adjusting the vertical `contentPadding` I can create the correct height.

This is still a bit of a faff and I don't see why the `constraints` field doesn't have any affect.

We can calculate the vertical padding programmatically.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const targetFieldHeight = 56.0;
    const fontSize = 20.0;
    const textHeight = 1.0;

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            // This represents the target height.
            Container(color: Colors.red, width: 4, height: targetFieldHeight),

            // The TextField.
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: TextField(
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, height: textHeight),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 16,
                      vertical: (targetFieldHeight - fontSize * textHeight) / 2,
                    ),
                    

                    // Fill color
                    fillColor: Colors.grey,
                    filled: true,

                    // Hint text
                    hintText: "Password",

                    // Borders
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      borderSide:
                          const BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On dart pad there was still a gap and by adding 4 to the vertical content padding that was resolved. There is no longer gap in my real project though.